# Primefaces 5.2 inputNumber não envia o valor atualizado ao Bean

Tags: primefaces

Quando o `submit` do `form` ocorre através do `enter`, estando com foco no `inputNumber` e alterando o seu conteúdo, este novo valor não atualiza a variável no `Bean`.
No entanto, se o `submit` ocorre através do clique no botão, o valor é enviado ao `Bean` corretamente.

```
<h:form id="meuForm">
...
    <pe:inputNumber id="categoria" value="#{bean.categoria}" decimalPlaces="0" required="true" requiredMessage="..." disabled="#{bean.categoriaDisabled}" emptyValue="empty" autocomplete="off">
        <f:validateLongRange minimum="1"/>
        <p:ajax listener="#{bean.categoriaChange}" update="valor"/>
    </pe:inputNumber>
...
    <p:commandButton id="btnSalvar" value="Salvar" actionListener="#{bean.salvar}" update="@form,:growl"/>
...
    <p:defaultCommand target="btnSalvar"/>
...
</h:form>
```

Provisoriamente, estou pegando o valor desta forma no `Bean`:

```
public void salvar() {
    String cat = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("meuForm:categoria_input");
    ...
}
```

Alguma ideia de como resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou setar o escopo de processamento do `p:commandButton`?

`process="@form"` ou `process=":meuForm"`

E talvez usar um `ajax="false"`.